# Node app using Mobile Application Security throws Unexpected token u when run locally

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've got a Node.js app that will be deployed to Bluemix. It makes use of Mobile Application Security. While developing, I'm testing locally. When I make an authenticated call from my mobile app to the local server, I get this in terminal:

> [INFO] [DEFAULT] Received request to
>   /saucedb/v1/apps/38a0a550-b018-4a10-b879-aec68868c249/all
>       SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
>           at Object.parse (native)
>           at getDomainNameFromVcapServices (/Users/raymondcamden/Dropbox/projects/saucedb/server/node_modules/ibmsecurity/js/masauth.js:19:28)
>           at getDomainName (/Users/raymondcamden/Dropbox/projects/saucedb/server/node_modules/ibmsecurity/js/masauth.js:99:22)
>           at getInternalMAMUrlServerName (/Users/raymondcamden/Dropbox/projects/saucedb/server/node_modules/ibmsecurity/js/masauth.js:115:22)
>           at postMasServiceRequestValidator (/Users/raymondcamden/Dropbox/projects/saucedb/server/node_modules/ibmsecurity/js/masauth.js:186:19)
>           at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/raymondcamden/Dropbox/projects/saucedb/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
>           at trim_prefix (/Users/raymondcamden/Dropbox/projects/saucedb/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
>           at /Users/raymondcamden/Dropbox/projects/saucedb/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
>           at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/raymondcamden/Dropbox/projects/saucedb/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
>           at Immediate.next (/Users/raymondcamden/Dropbox/projects/saucedb/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)

It is failing - as far as I can see - in getDomainNameFromVcapServices. I'm running locally without a proper domain so perhaps that is it - but I'm unsure as to how to get around this.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](https://hub.jazz.net/project/bluemixmobilesdk/ibmsecurity/overview), it's failing to parse the application credentials which are stored in the VCAP_SERVICES environment parameter.

```
var vcapService = JSON.parse(process.env['VCAP_SERVICES']);
```

This value is [automatically populated](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html) when running on a Cloud Foundry platform.

You can set up the same values locally:

```
$ export VCAP_SERVICES="..."
```

... before running your local application.

Use the following command to review the remote credentials that can be used locally.

```
$ cf env APP_NAME
```

Comment: That makes sense - but what should i use for the value?

Comment: In the Bluemix console, your application dashboard should show all the services that are abound to the app. There should be a button under each service that says "Show Crendentials". You can copy that.

Comment: Ah, duh, ok, thats makes sense. Will try it.

Comment: Well wait... I need one string, not multi, so do I take each service and combine them into one JSON string? There's no way to get them all at once?

Comment: Ok, I went with *just* the MAS credentials and it looks to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I lie. I used this, https://gist.github.com/cfjedimaster/ba5d34a568af68c5eac6, and I still get an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token M

Comment: Ok, found the *global* vcap services in the left hand nav. That's gotten rid of the issue. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be able to communicate anymore ot the remote db provider. That's another issue though.

Comment: I did write a plugin for CF CLI to make this easier to automate: https://github.com/jthomas/copyenv